# Encontrar el índice de una matriz en java

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como encontrar el índice de las filas y las columnas de una matriz dada. Por ejemplo, si me dan una matriz a[5][7] como sacaría dichos valores en un método?

Comment: Lo ideal es que quien pregunte pueda aportar el código implementado, para poder ayudarle.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que repases el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), que esta no es tu primera pregunta. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si lo que indicas es que, a  través de un método, deseas obtener el valor de la matriz con el indice para fila y columna ya indicado, en caso tal que sea así, guíate de esto:

```
package javaapplication3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 {
    
     static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        
        int fila, columna;
        fila=10; columna=10;    
        int matriz[][] =  new int[fila][columna];       
        
        //suponiendo que la matriz ya tiene datos...        
        buscarElemento(fila, columna, matriz);
        
    }    
    public static int buscarElemento(int fila, int columna, int matriz[][]) {
        
        int filaBuscar, columnaBuscar;
        
        //para verificar que no se acceda a una pocision inexistente de la matriz
        do{
            
            System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de la fila y columna del elemento a buscar : ");
            filaBuscar=sc.nextInt();
            columnaBuscar=sc.nextInt();
            
        }while( (filaBuscar>fila || columnaBuscar>columna) || (filaBuscar<=0 || columnaBuscar<=0) );
        
        int elemento = matriz[filaBuscar][columnaBuscar];
        
        return elemento;        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Está bien ayudar a quien lo necesite, pero no es bueno mal acostumbrar a las personas haciendoles las cosas, sin tener si quiera algún intento de su parte. El cual podemos evidenciar cuando se comparte lo realizado por la persona quien pregunta.